# 18.04 i-386 installs, gives ibus.rc error

Tags: system-installation, 18.04, 32-bit, ibus

After successful net install of i-386 Ubuntu Mate 18.04, an error displayed when booting/starting up. (after the login screen completes.)

"/usr/share/im-config/data/21_ibus.rc line 6: 
     /usr/bin/ibus-daemon: No such file or directory.

As a result, The session will not be configured correctly.
You should fix the problem as soon as possible.
"

I looked at the rc file. Lic 6 starts the ibus Daemon.
It is missing.
I also did a sudo find / -print | grep ibus-daemon 
None was found

My opinion is that is is an install bug - the daemon was left out.

As a hunch, I installed libibus-1.0-5, and restarted.
That did not solve the problem.

Any suggestions?
Write a bug report?

Thanks!
Jay

Answer (score 0):

Package `ibus-daemon` is a keyboard input method. I got the same error seemingly caused by an `Ubuntu 18.04` update.

I was able to fix it by going to `Settings > Region and Langauge > Language Support` and changing the `Keyboard input method system` to `XIM`.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BF00r.png)